# Internationalization in Yii2 (Database)

Tags: internationalization, yii2

I'm kinda struggling what is going on right now.
I want to set up a site with multilanguage-functionality. For that, I read the topic about Internationalization in the guides. I don't want to use the text-/file-version, I want to use the DB instead.

I found out, that there is something like the DbMessageSource. I applied the migration and have the following tables in my DB:

`message`
`message_source`

In my config-file, I addes these lines:

```
'components' => [
    'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
    ],
    'i18n' => [
        'translations' => [
            '*' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\DbMessageSource',
                'forceTranslation' => true,
                'sourceMessageTable' => '{{%source_message}}',
                'messageTable' => '{{%message}}',
                'enableCaching' => false,
                'cachingDuration' => 3600,
                'sourceLanguage' => 'en_US'
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

In my view, I call the translation-function like this:

```
echo yii::t('header_menu', 'news');
```

It is actually displaying "news", but regardless of the `language` I set, nothing is stored in the DB. Am I missing something? I thought every string, which is in a translate-function would be stored in the DB?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

By itself it won't be in DB. It just selects if data is already there. You should do it by yourself or use lajax translate manager extension, it will scan all your project automatically and fill database with messages.